# Using nodejs & react together (in electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I have a React component which I use in my electron application.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import SentenceView from '../components/SentenceView';
import Dictionary from '../components/Dictionary';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
  render() {
    const aTestArray = [1,2,3,4];

    return (
      <div>
        <SentenceView numbers={aTestArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am giving my SentenceView component aTestArray. Now, in reality I won't have this array available but will need to create it myself. Since React is only the View, I do not want to create the array with React, but outsource this to a function I have written in nodejs. It creates an array and then returns it. So what (as of now) I have written as

```
    const sentenceArray = ['Hello', 'Mister'];
```

would ideally look something like this then:

```
    const sentenceArray = createTheArrayFunction(); //returns array
```

However, I do not know how I can make this work. I do not know how to give my React component access to function which is in a nodejs file, or how else I would connect the two. I am using electron, so it should be possible for me to use nodejs (somewhere somehow). But I just have no clue how to put these things together. I would be glad if someone could help me out.

Comment: When you instantiate / render `HomePage`, you should pass the array as a prop.

Comment: Thank you. I instantiate HomePage within another React Component. Shall I give it to this component then, and have this component pass it on? It seems overly complicated to me to go through the whole tree structure of my application, just to pass over a simple array to a relatively simple component, simply because I do want to separate the view from the logic - or am I misunderstanding something here?